# Why there is strange circle around the checkbox?

Tags: html, checkbox, input

I use input to create a toggle switch as below

```
    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
```

But there is a blue circle around the checkbox, is there anybody know why?
thanks in advance!

[image: display when checkbox is clicked]

Comment: Add more relevant code. On the screen isn't a checkbox.

Comment: <div><input type="checkbox" checked=""></div>  decorate it via css, and then it displayed as picture, can switch Enable/Disable by clicking it.

Comment: No, on the screen really isn't a checkbox.

Comment: it is `outline` you can turn it of with css by setting `outline: 0;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.

Comment: Look at my solution

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a focus line on the button or whatever the picture is. The code below should make the line go away :D.

```
input[type='checkbox']:focus {outline: none}
```